# PHPExcel style problem

Tags: php, phpexcel

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Name');
```

1.How I set this to bold?

2.How I set the width(I will have some dinamic text in the cells!)?

I have read the documentation, but I haven't found any solutions!

Answer (score 7):

Bold:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
```

Width:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->setWidth(15);
```

Not tested though.

Answer (score 0):

$col zero 0 based

> $worksheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($col)->setWidth($width);

Hi 2009