# PHP style excel sheets

Tags: php, excel

I am trying to export excel file from the mysql as per the answer in

> [Exporting data to excel sheet in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284017/exporting-data-to-excel-sheet-in-php). The export is successful. But I would like to know about the styles. Can I make one line bold, italic etc in the excel file? And can I insert a table using this excel export?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+excel+styling

Comment: Tab or comma separated value files don't contain style information, even when you give them an extension of .xls; you need a library that can write a real xls format file to do that

Comment: In addition to my own PHPExcel library (http://phpexcel.codeplex.com) you'll find a pretty comprehensive list of other PHP libraries for writing Excel files here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel

Answer (score -1):

https://www.google.com/search?q=php+excel+styling

yeilds:

[PHPExcel: Coloring the cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164787/phpexcel-coloring-the-cells)

[PHPExcel specific cell formatting from style object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918586/phpexcel-specific-cell-formatting-from-style-object)

[PHPExcel style problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858557/phpexcel-style-problem)

[PHP Excel style formatting using col & row index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836688/php-excel-style-formatting-using-col-row-index)

[Style a range of cells with phpexcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675844/style-a-range-of-cells-with-phpexcel)

[PHPexcel cannot reads styles from xls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979394/phpexcel-cannot-reads-styles-from-xls)

SO is endless with information, and that's just the first page of results

Comment: Thank you. I have searched in the google. But the style is for PHP Excel class, I am afraid. I haven't installed the PHP Excel class

Comment: working with Microsoft Excel is a nightmare. People have tried and tested different classes repeatedly. Find the best one that both fits your needs and has a high response rate, and try one. If you don't like it, don't use it.